# How can I remove the sunken inner edge of an MDI client window?

Tags: delphi, mdi, delphi-xe3

The other day, I started to develop my new project. There should be a MDI form with some child forms on it. But when I started to develop, I ran into a following problem: when the main form becomes MDI-form, it draws with а terrible border (bevel) inside. And I can't  take it away. You can see this situation at the screenshot:

[image: http://s18.postimg.org/k3hqpdocp/mdi_problem.png]

Oppositely, a MDI-Child form draws without the same bevel.

The project contains two forms, Form1 and Form2. Form1 is a main MDI form.

Form1 source code:

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 346
  ClientWidth = 439
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  FormStyle = fsMDIForm
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
end
```

Form2 source code:

```
object Form2: TForm2
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form2'
  ClientHeight = 202
  ClientWidth = 331
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  FormStyle = fsMDIChild
  OldCreateOrder = False
  Visible = True
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
end
```

**Please, tell me how can I take this bevel away from the main form.**

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The border is drawn because the MDI client window has the extended window style [`WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ff700543.aspx#WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE). This style is described thus:

> The window has a border with a sunken edge.

However, my first simple attempts to remove that style failed. For example you can try this code:

```
procedure TMyMDIForm.CreateWnd;
var
  ExStyle: DWORD;
begin
  inherited;
  ExStyle := GetWindowLongPtr(ClientHandle, GWL_EXSTYLE);
  SetWindowLongPtr(ClientHandle, GWL_EXSTYLE,
    ExStyle and not WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE);
  SetWindowPos(ClientHandle, 0, 0,0,0,0, SWP_FRAMECHANGED or 
    SWP_NOACTIVATE or SWP_NOMOVE or SWP_NOSIZE or SWP_NOZORDER);
end;
```

This code does indeed remove `WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE`. But you cannot see any visual change and if you inspect the window using a tool like Spy++ then you will see that the MDI client window retains `WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE`.

So, what gives? It turns out that the MDI client window's window procedure (implemented in the VCL code) is forcing the client edge to be shown. And this overrides any attempts that you make to remove the style.

The code in question looks like this:

```
procedure ShowMDIClientEdge(ClientHandle: THandle; ShowEdge: Boolean);
var
  Style: Longint;
begin
  if ClientHandle <> 0 then
  begin
    Style := GetWindowLong(ClientHandle, GWL_EXSTYLE);
    if ShowEdge then
      if Style and WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE = 0 then
        Style := Style or WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE
      else
        Exit
    else if Style and WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE <> 0 then
      Style := Style and not WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE
    else
      Exit;
    SetWindowLong(ClientHandle, GWL_EXSTYLE, Style);
    SetWindowPos(ClientHandle, 0, 0,0,0,0, SWP_FRAMECHANGED or 
      SWP_NOACTIVATE or SWP_NOMOVE or SWP_NOSIZE or SWP_NOZORDER);
  end;
end;
....
procedure TCustomForm.ClientWndProc(var Message: TMessage);
....
begin
  with Message do
    case Msg of
      ....
      $3F://!
        begin
          Default;
          if FFormStyle = fsMDIForm then
            ShowMDIClientEdge(ClientHandle, (MDIChildCount = 0) or
              not MaximizedChildren);
        end;
```

So, you simply need to override the handling of this `$3F` message.

Do that like this:

```
type
  TMyMDIForm = class(TForm)
  protected
    procedure ClientWndProc(var Message: TMessage); override;
  end;

procedure TMyMDIForm.ClientWndProc(var Message: TMessage);
var
  ExStyle: DWORD;
begin
  case Message.Msg of
  $3F:
    begin
      ExStyle := GetWindowLongPtr(ClientHandle, GWL_EXSTYLE);
      ExStyle := ExStyle and not WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE;
      SetWindowLongPtr(ClientHandle, GWL_EXSTYLE, ExStyle);
      SetWindowPos(ClientHandle, 0, 0,0,0,0, SWP_FRAMECHANGED or 
        SWP_NOACTIVATE or SWP_NOMOVE or SWP_NOSIZE or SWP_NOZORDER);
    end;
  else
    inherited;
  end;
end;
```

The end result looks like this:

[image]

Note that the code above does not call the default window procedure. I'm not sure whether or not that will cause other problems but it's very plausible that other MDI behaviour will be affected. So, you may need to implement a more capable behaviour patch. Hopefully this answer gives you the knowledge you need to make your application behave the way you desire.

---

I was thinking a bit more about how to implement a comprehensive solution that ensured the default window procedure was called for the `$3F` message, whatever that message happens to be. It's not trivial to achieve since the default window procedure is stored in a private field `FDefClientProc`. Which makes it rather hard to reach.

I suppose you could use a class helper to crack the private members. But I prefer a different approach. My approach would be to leave the window procedure exactly as it is, and hook the calls that the VCL code makes to `SetWindowLong`. Whenever the VCL tries to add the `WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE` for an MDI client window, the hooked code can block that style.

The implementation looks like this:

```
type
  TMyMDIForm = class(TForm)
  protected
    procedure CreateWnd; override;
  end;

procedure PatchCode(Address: Pointer; const NewCode; Size: Integer);
var
  OldProtect: DWORD;
begin
  if VirtualProtect(Address, Size, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, OldProtect) then
  begin
    Move(NewCode, Address^, Size);
    FlushInstructionCache(GetCurrentProcess, Address, Size);
    VirtualProtect(Address, Size, OldProtect, @OldProtect);
  end;
end;

type
  PInstruction = ^TInstruction;
  TInstruction = packed record
    Opcode: Byte;
    Offset: Integer;
  end;

procedure RedirectProcedure(OldAddress, NewAddress: Pointer);
var
  NewCode: TInstruction;
begin
  NewCode.Opcode := $E9;//jump relative
  NewCode.Offset := NativeInt(NewAddress)-NativeInt(OldAddress)-SizeOf(NewCode);
  PatchCode(OldAddress, NewCode, SizeOf(NewCode));
end;

function SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd: HWND; nIndex: Integer; dwNewLong: LONG_PTR): LONG_PTR; stdcall; external user32 name 'SetWindowLongW';

function MySetWindowLongPtr(hWnd: HWND; nIndex: Integer; dwNewLong: LONG_PTR): LONG_PTR; stdcall;
var
  ClassName: array [0..63] of Char;
begin
  if GetClassName(hWnd, ClassName, Length(ClassName))>0 then
    if (ClassName='MDIClient') and (nIndex=GWL_EXSTYLE) then
      dwNewLong := dwNewLong and not WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE;
  Result := SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, nIndex, dwNewLong);
end;

procedure TMyMDIForm.CreateWnd;
var
  ExStyle: DWORD;
begin
  inherited;
  // unless we remove WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE here, ShowMDIClientEdge never calls SetWindowLong
  ExStyle := GetWindowLongPtr(ClientHandle, GWL_EXSTYLE);
  SetWindowLongPtr(ClientHandle, GWL_EXSTYLE, ExStyle and not WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE);
end;

initialization
  RedirectProcedure(@Winapi.Windows.SetWindowLongPtr, @MySetWindowLongPtr);
```

---

Or if you prefer the version that uses a private member class helper crack, that looks like this:

```
type
  TFormHelper = class helper for TCustomForm
    function DefClientProc: TFarProc;
  end;

function TFormHelper.DefClientProc: TFarProc;
begin
  Result := Self.FDefClientProc;
end;

type
  TMyMDIForm = class(TForm)
  protected
    procedure ClientWndProc(var Message: TMessage); override;
  end;

procedure TMyMDIForm.ClientWndProc(var Message: TMessage);
var
  ExStyle: DWORD;
begin
  case Message.Msg of
  $3F:
    begin
      Message.Result := CallWindowProc(DefClientProc, ClientHandle, Message.Msg, Message.wParam, Message.lParam);
      ExStyle := GetWindowLongPtr(ClientHandle, GWL_EXSTYLE);
      ExStyle := ExStyle and not WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE;
      SetWindowLongPtr(ClientHandle, GWL_EXSTYLE, ExStyle);
      SetWindowPos(ClientHandle, 0, 0,0,0,0, SWP_FRAMECHANGED or
        SWP_NOACTIVATE or SWP_NOMOVE or SWP_NOSIZE or SWP_NOZORDER);
    end;
  else
    inherited;
  end;
end;
```

Finally, I thank you for the very interesting question. It was certainly a lot of fun exploring this problem!

Comment: Seems to me you do need to call the default window procedure.

Comment: @kobik OK, I've nailed it now.

Comment: Cool. Don't sound surprised though!  ;-)

Comment: Alternatively (for the last part) you can call `inherited` before modifying the frame, and remove the extraneous `$3F` (apparently which the `SetWindowPos` call causes to be posted again) with `PeekMessage`. That will save the redirection code. .. +1 regardless..

Comment: @Sertac Thanks. The extraneous $3F leads to the flickering. I didn't chase that.

Comment: The solution with redirect does not seem to work in Delphi 10.1 Berlin.

Comment: @Reynaldi class helpers don't crack privates in berlin. And for the other code perhaps the VCL implementation changed since XE3 in some important detail. This answer provides all the detail needed to investigate and is kit meant as a black box.

Answer (score 2):

You could use my open source component [`NLDExtraMDIProps`](http://www.nldelphi.com/forum/showthread.php?t=24700) (downloadable from [here](https://github.com/NLDelphi/NLDExtraMDIProps)), which has a `ShowClientEdge` property for just that. (The code is similar to that of [David's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16129354/757830), although I am interception `WM_NCCALCSIZE`, rather then `$3F`).

In addition to that, the component also has the following convenient MDI properties:

- `BackgroundPicture`: an image from disk, resources, or DFM to be painted in the center of the client window.
- `CleverMaximizing`: rearranging multiple MDI clients by double clicking on their title bars, and thus *maximizing* it to the largest free space in the MDI Form.
- `ShowScrollBars`: turn MDI Form's scroll bars on or off when dragging a client beyond the MDI Form extends.